# java+json: how to get an element from a json object that contains an array of objects {[ {},{} ]}

Tags: java, arrays, json, object

Need some help with java+json. 
Hi to everyone! I need to sort data by song title and provide processing of exceptional situations. I need to write the method that sorts the data from json file. This method must also be able to sort the data with the same fields for example. The parsing of this file works. But it hase a a structure as:

```
{
    "musicAlbum": [
        {
            "groupname": "twenty one pilots",
            "songduration": 3.27,
            "songname": "Heathens"
        },
        {
            "groupname": "twenty one pilots",
            "songduration": 4.4,
            "songname": "Car Radio"
        },
        {
            "groupname": "Linkin Park",
            "songduration": 3.06,
            "songname": "Numb"
        }
    ]
}
```

and I don't now how to get any element from objects Array. For example when I try to do: .getSongName(), I get "null".

I have the class Record with String groupName; String songName; and double songDuration; all geters and seters. Also JsonParser class with parsing method. And MusicAlbum class with List album. And also class with main:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException // exception to be 
handled
{
    List<Record> album = JsonParser.parseJson();
    System.out.println(album); 

    for (int i = 0; i < album.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(album.get(i));
    }
    Record songName = new Record();
    System.out.println(songName); 
    System.out.println(songName.getSongName());

}
}
```

What I have in console now:

```
[MusicAlbum [album=[Record [groupName=twenty one pilots, songName=Heathens, songDuration=3.27] , Record [groupName=twenty one pilots, songName=Car Radio, songDuration=4.4] , Record [groupName=Linkin Park, songName=Numb, songDuration=3.06] , Record [groupName=Lana Del Rey, songName=Summertime sadness, songDuration=3.56] , Record [groupName=Imagine Dragons, songName=Thunder, songDuration=3.24] , Record [groupName=Three Days Grace, songName=Outsider, songDuration=2.43] , Record [groupName=ONUKA, songName=When I Met You, songDuration=4.04] , Record [groupName=Foster The People, songName=Best Friend, songDuration=4.25] , Record [groupName=Massive Attack, songName=Angel, songDuration=6.18] , Record [groupName=Florence + The Machine, songName=Big God, songDuration=4.28] , Record [groupName=Die antwoord, songName=banana brain, songDuration=7.12] , Record [groupName=Coldplay, songName=Hypnotised, songDuration=5.54] ]]]

MusicAlbum [album=[Record [groupName=twenty one pilots, songName=Heathens, songDuration=3.27] , Record [groupName=twenty one pilots, songName=Car Radio, songDuration=4.4] , Record [groupName=Linkin Park, songName=Numb, songDuration=3.06] , Record [groupName=Lana Del Rey, songName=Summertime sadness, songDuration=3.56] , Record [groupName=Imagine Dragons, songName=Thunder, songDuration=3.24] , Record [groupName=Three Days Grace, songName=Outsider, songDuration=2.43] , Record [groupName=ONUKA, songName=When I Met You, songDuration=4.04] , Record [groupName=Foster The People, songName=Best Friend, songDuration=4.25] , Record [groupName=Massive Attack, songName=Angel, songDuration=6.18] , Record [groupName=Florence + The Machine, songName=Big God, songDuration=4.28] , Record [groupName=Die antwoord, songName=banana brain, songDuration=7.12] , Record [groupName=Coldplay, songName=Hypnotised, songDuration=5.54] ]]

Record [groupName=null, songName=null, songDuration=0.0] 

null
```

And I don't have idea, what to do and how to write a method for a data reciving.

Thanks for any help with this method!

Comment: Please include the code for other classes, especially `Record`.

Comment: What are you parsing? Where's the JSON string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, without more details about your `Record` class and your parser, I can only do some reverse engineering.

This is how your data looks like.

```
MusicAlbum [
    album= [
        Record [groupName=twenty one pilots, songName=Heathens, songDuration=3.27] ,
        Record [groupName=twenty one pilots, songName=Car Radio, songDuration=4.4] ,
        Record [groupName=Linkin Park, songName=Numb, songDuration=3.06] ,
        Record [groupName=Lana Del Rey, songName=Summertime sadness, songDuration=3.56] ,
        Record [groupName=Imagine Dragons, songName=Thunder, songDuration=3.24] ,
        Record [groupName=Three Days Grace, songName=Outsider, songDuration=2.43] ,
        Record [groupName=ONUKA, songName=When I Met You, songDuration=4.04] ,
        Record [groupName=Foster The People, songName=Best Friend, songDuration=4.25] ,
        Record [groupName=Massive Attack, songName=Angel, songDuration=6.18] ,
        Record [groupName=Florence + The Machine, songName=Big God, songDuration=4.28] ,
        Record [groupName=Die antwoord, songName=banana brain, songDuration=7.12] , Record [groupName=Coldplay, songName=Hypnotised, songDuration=5.54]
    ]
]
```

A `MusicAlbum` has an array of `records` and each record has some fields, `songName` being one of them.

So, the overall algorithm to get record details would be something like this:

```
List<Album> albums = parseJson("{...}");
for (Album album : albums) {
    // 'album' is a bad name here, it's storing records, not albums
    List<Record> records = album.getAlbum();
    for (Record record : records) {
        System.out.println(record.getSonName());
    }
}
```

This basically pseudocode, it won't compile, just to give you an idea.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. The mistake was in the parsing class. Because it parses an array list, but json has an object. So the parsing class must pars an object.

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding any values to your songName object:

```
Record songName = new Record(); // you should add values to "songName" object
System.out.println(songName); 
System.out.println(songName.getSongName());
```

Therefore, everything is null.
Try doing something like this:

Add your response "musicAlbum" to JSONArray object, than iterate through that array and obtain each record.

```
List<Record> records = new ArrayList<>();
Record record = new Record();

for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++) {
    JSONObject jObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

    record.setGroupName = jObj.getString("groupname");
    record.setSongName = jObj.getString("songname");
    record.setSongDuration = jObj.getString("songduration");

    records.add(record);
}
```